# Excel 2010 won't remember password when importing data

Tags: microsoft-excel, passwords, database, import

After connecting an Excel workbook with an SQL server (within a company network, over a static IP address, using the data connection wizard within Excel), if I close the workbook and reopen it, it requires me to type in the password for the server again.

Is there a way for the connection to *always* remember the password, not just the username?

Comment: Did you [allow saving password](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/277600) in the connection wizard?